# Storing a pointer to a function with any return type and any number or arguments

Tags: c++, function, types, function-pointers

I'm writing a custom JIT (interpreted) programming language called `Trunk`, and I'm trying to parse functions from code and store them in a global name -> function map, for now. But I'm stuck figuring out what type to use for the second template argument of `std::map`. Here is what I have so far:

```cpp
namespace trunk {
    template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
    class Function {
        using FunctionType = Ret (*)(Args...);
        
        public:
            Function(FunctionType callable): _callable(callable) {}
            ~Function() {}
            
            Ret operator(Args... args) { 
                return _callable(args...);
            }
        
        protected:
            FunctionType _callable;
    };

    namespace globals {
        void print(std::string s) {
            std::cout << s << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

static trunk::Function print_function = trunk::Function(&trunk::globals::print);
static std::map< std::string, trunk::Function > function_map = {
    {"print", &print_function},
};
```

But that throws the following errors:

```cpp
In file included from /media/frederic/WD-5TB/.fg/Programme/trunk/src/main.cxx:5:
/media/frederic/WD-5TB/.fg/Programme/trunk/include/trunk/function.hxx:15:37: error: expected type-specifier before ‘(’ token
   15 |                         Ret operator(Args... args) {
      |                                     ^
/media/frederic/WD-5TB/.fg/Programme/trunk/src/main.cxx:16:47: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> class std::map’
   16 | static std::map< std::string, trunk::Function > function_map = {
      |                                               ^
/media/frederic/WD-5TB/.fg/Programme/trunk/src/main.cxx:16:47: note:   expected a type, got ‘Function’
/media/frederic/WD-5TB/.fg/Programme/trunk/src/main.cxx:16:47: error: template argument 4 is invalid
/media/frederic/WD-5TB/.fg/Programme/trunk/src/main.cxx:18:1: error: too many braces around scalar initializer for type ‘int’
   18 | };
      | ^
```

Comment: `trunk::Function` is not a type, so you can't have a map of them.  You'll need to rethink your design to either avoid having a heterogeneous map of functions or to type-erase your function callables and do runtime checking on their signatures.

Comment: One compiler error is from incorrect syntax of `operator()` declaration, it should be `Ret operator()(Args... args)`

Comment: What operator? I guess `operator()`? `operator` is just a keyword, that is followed by the operator name `()` and the operator arguments.

Comment: As for the main issue, I think you should have non-templated `Function` and store information about its arguments, return type etc as data members. Types in your (interpreted, as it seems) language don't have to be types in your C++ code, you read them in runtime during interpretation after all. Calling a `Function` with some arguments, interpreted from code in your language, then will employ checking the signature in runtime.

Comment: @237K ah yeah, how easy it is to overlook that extra pair of parentheses … XD

Comment: @Miles Budnek uh why not ?

Comment: @YurkoFlisk `store information about its arguments, return type etc as data members` - ok, but I don't see a way to pass that data from the parser to the function object without templates ?

Comment: Suppose you somehow managed to define `std::map<std::string, Something> function_map;` How would you use it? How would you know which parameters of which types each entry takes, and how would you supply arguments to the call? Show an example of the expected usage pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trunk::Function` is not a type; it is a template: a blueprint from which any number of different types can be created.  For example,  `trunk::Function<void, int>` is a different type from `trunk::Function<int, double>`.

Since there is no single `trunk::Function` type you can't create a `std::map<std::string, trunk::Function>`.

If you want to have a single, heterogeneous map of all of your functions, you'll need to create some sort of type-erased wrapper around them and check the number and type of arguments and the type of return value at runtime.

Here's a fairly basic example that does that:

```cpp
namespace trunk {
    class FunctionImplBase
    {
    public:
        virtual std::any call(const std::vector<std::any>& args) = 0;
    };
    
    template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
    class FunctionImpl : public FunctionImplBase
    {
    private:
        using FunctionType = Ret (*)(Args...);
        FunctionType callable_;

    public:
        FunctionImpl(FunctionType callable) : callable_{callable} {}
        
        std::any call(const std::vector<std::any>& args) override
        {
            if (args.size() != sizeof...(Args)) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Wrong number of arguments supplied");
            }
            
            return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Ret, void>) {
                    callable_(std::any_cast<Args>(args[Is])...);
                    return std::any{};
                } else {
                    return callable_(std::any_cast<Args>(args[Is])...);
                }
            }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{});
        }
    };
    
    class Function
    {
        public:
            Function() {}
        
            template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
            Function(Ret(*callable)(Args...))
                : impl_{std::make_shared<FunctionImpl<Ret, Args...>>(callable)}
            {}
            
            std::any operator()(const std::vector<std::any>& args) const {
                return impl_->call(args);
            }
        
        private:
            std::shared_ptr<FunctionImplBase> impl_;
    };
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bfc21c8d48ee3fb)

The basic idea is that `Function` accepts any number of any type of argument, and then uses a polymorphic, type-erased `FunctionImpl` instantiation to check if it was given the number and type of arguments that the function it holds expects.

Note that this implementation has some shortcomings.  Namely around reference parameters.  It's intended to show a possible approach you could take, more than a complete solution.